# Git error: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters

Tags: eclipse, git, character-encoding, runtime-error, filenames

My Eclipse workspace has two projects, one using CVS, the other Git.  When modifying a file in the CVS project and save, a pop-up window appear saying

```
An internal error occurred during: "Computing Git status for repository repo23".
Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters: /Users/pb/repo23/对照表/feng11.htm
```

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

Eclipse Platform

Version: 4.3.1.v20130911-1000
Build id: M20130911-1000

Eclipse EGit 3.2.0.201312181205-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see the exact call stack in [this issue](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/clickstack-framework/issues/4):

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters: /Users/jettykoo/Desktop/WeTeam/Git/WSS/MaryKay/Doc/01/.DS_Store
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2186)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtil.isFile(FileUtil.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtil.canExecute(FileUtil.java:131)
```

I was surprised by the typo in [sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java#118) : 'chacraters' instead of 'characters'!

As mentioned in [this NetBeans issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225743) (which should be relevant in an Eclipse context):

> it's a **[JDK issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8003228)** and also partially also Apple issue (the `LC_CTYPE` is not set by default).
> The behaviour in terminal depends on the `Terminal.app` preferences.

> - When the Terminal export `LC_CTYPE` set to `UTF-8` it works fine in terminal as the `sun.jnu.encoding` is set to the value of `LC_CTYPE`.

- When it's not set it does not work.

> The problem with setting the `sun.jnu.encoding` is that it may be overwritten by the JDK, so it's safer to export the `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8`.

> Rather then addding `-J-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` to `netbeans.conf`, prepend the export `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` to it.

You could set this in your [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) (`-DLC_CTYPE=UTF-8`).

---

[Alexander Kachkaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818285/alexander-kachkaev) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413421/git-error-malformed-input-or-input-contains-unmappable-chacraters/22421189#comment52658355_22421189):

> What helped me was adding two lines to `eclipse.ini`.

```
-DLC_CTYPE=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

> Team commands stopped giving errors

Comment: After adding `-DLC_CTYPE=UTF-8` to eclipse.ini, when editing file in the CVS project and save, the said error no longer appear.  But when saving after editing a file in the Git project, the same error window appears.

Comment: What helped me was adding two lines to ```eclipse.ini```. First: ```-DLC_CTYPE=UTF-8```, second: ```-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8```. Team commands stopped giving errors.

Comment: @AlexanderKachkaev Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have this problem on an Alpine Linux Docker image (but strangely enough, not on my OSX machine).

Comment: @mhvelplund Then try presenting that issue as a new question here (with a link back to this answer for context).

Comment: @VonC not yet, I'm looking for a solution :) I just wanted to note that the issue can occur in other places, so it's not Eclipse specific.

Comment: @mhvelplund OK, good point. Let us know when you find a solution ;)

Comment: Fast forwarding to 2023-6, can anyone verify if adding these two lines are still necessary or relevant in the newest version of Eclipse?

Comment: @MengLu Those JVM arguments (used to set the default character encoding and locale for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM)) should still be relevant today.

Answer (score 4):

The above properties didn't work for me. However, setting these environment variables did:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: What versions of Eclipse and Mac OS X (if that's your OS) is yours?

Comment: Eclipse Juno on Mac OS X leopard (10.7?)

Comment: Actually I just remembered I executed the git command from the shell, not eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

this workaround has no effect. After updating eclipse to 2021-09, the git plugin (or another code) tries to change the charset of SQL files, generating error (does not complete pull).  git in command line it works perfectly