# Continuous Git error in Eclipse after many attempts to fix: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, jgit

I have been receiving this error every time I try to commit a project I've been working on in Eclipse. I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413421/git-error-malformed-input-or-input-contains-unmappable-chacraters) thread as well as others on other sites and no solutions I've tried have worked so far. It seems to be a problem with Eclipse not recognizing the 'µ' character. I am on a Mac running OS X Mavericks with Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error occurred computing diffs
Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters: /Users/Tom/Desktop/Movies and TV Shows/Boardwalk Empire/TSV/µTorrent Set Up Guide - uTorrent Set Up Guide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the mentioned path contained in a repository that is connected in Eclipse?

Open the *Git Repositories* view and see if it contains any unusual entries, like a "Tom" repository or something like that. If it does and you do not use it, try removing it from the view using the context menu.

Comment: Just did that and it works! Thanks! For others who may have the same problem: remember to Disconnect your project and then reconnect it.

Comment: Great! FYI, automatically connecting to the home directory was an issue in EGit which has been fixed in 3.0.2, see [bug 393332](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393332). Note that once such a repo is connected, the problem persists even after upgrading EGit, that's why you have to remove the repo.