# java environment or charset settings that can influence File.getCanonicalPath

Tags: java, character-encoding, jvm

I want to create a folder with Chinese characters, but get wrong folder name. Chinese characters are replaced by **'?'**. Here is my code:

```
    String pathname = "/tmp/测试-" + Bytes.toHexLower(Bytes.random(16));
    File file = new File(pathname);
    log.info("test", "pathname=[" + pathname + "]");
    log.info("test", "path=[" + file.getPath() + "]");
    log.info("test", "file.encoding=[" + System.getProperty("file.encoding") + "]");
    log.info("test", "defaultCharset=[" + Charset.defaultCharset() + "]");
    try {
        log.info("test", "canonicalPath=[" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "]");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("test", e);
    }
    file.mkdir();
```

The log is:

```
    pathname=[/tmp/测试-7ba077d59e8b6b550fe4f032fc30afda]
    path=[/tmp/测试-7ba077d59e8b6b550fe4f032fc30afda]
    canonicalPath=[/tmp/??-7ba077d59e8b6b550fe4f032fc30afda]
    file.encoding=[UTF-8]
    defaultCharset=[UTF-8]
```

Filename "/tmp/测试-7ba0..." changes to "/tmp/??-7ba0...", but file.encoding and defaultCharset seem no problem.

Are there any other environment or charset settings that can influence File.getCanonicalPath ?

**UPDATE-1**

I added the following codes to dump System.getenv() :

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : new TreeMap<>(System.getenv()).entrySet()) {
        log.info("test", "env(" + entry.getKey() + ")=[" + entry.getValue() + "]");
    }
```

In the environment that creates *wrong* folder name, I got:

```
    env(CONSOLETYPE)=[vt]
    env(JAVA_OPTS)=[-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
    env(LANG)=[en_US.UTF-8]
    env(LANGSH_SOURCED)=[1]
    env(LC_ALL)=[C]
    env(NLSPATH)=[/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat]
    env(PATH)=[/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin]
    env(PREVLEVEL)=[N]
    env(PWD)=[/root]
    env(RUNLEVEL)=[3]
    env(SHLVL)=[4]
    env(TERM)=[linux]
    env(UPSTART_EVENTS)=[runlevel]
    env(UPSTART_INSTANCE)=[]
    env(UPSTART_JOB)=[rc]
    env(XFILESEARCHPATH)=[/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt]
    env(_)=[/usr/bin/java]
    env(previous)=[N]
    env(runlevel)=[3]
```

That tomcat (startup.sh) may be started with a python script.

In the environment that creates *correct* folder name, I got:

```
    env(ENV_GROUP)=[FAT]
    env(ENV_NAME)=[T6]
    env(HISTSIZE)=[1000]
    env(HOME)=[/root]
    env(HOSTNAME)=[t6.dcfservice.com]
    env(LANG)=[en_US.UTF-8]
    env(LC_ALL)=[en_US.UTF-8]
    env(LOGNAME)=[root]
    env(LS_COLORS)=[rs=0:di=01;...
    env(MAIL)=[/var/spool/mail/develop]
    env(NLSPATH)=[/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat]
    env(PATH)=[/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin]
    env(PWD)=[/home/develop]
    env(SHELL)=[/bin/bash]
    env(SHLVL)=[2]
    env(SUDO_COMMAND)=[/usr/bin/restart_tomcat.sh]
    env(SUDO_GID)=[1503]
    env(SUDO_UID)=[1503]
    env(SUDO_USER)=[develop]
    env(TERM)=[vt100]
    env(USER)=[root]
    env(USERNAME)=[root]
    env(XFILESEARCHPATH)=[/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt]
    env(_)=[/usr/bin/java]
```

That tomcat is started with SSH client.

**UPDATE-2**

Use *Path* according to VGR and zapl's suggestion:

```
    try {
        pathname = "/tmp/测试-" + Bytes.toHexLower(Bytes.random(16));
        Path path = Paths.get(pathname);
        log.info("test", "pathname=[" + pathname + "]");
        Files.createDirectory(path);
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException | IOException e) {
        log.error("test", e);
    }
```

In the first tomcat (started by a python script), I got:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.iqunxing.cashier.Context
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /tmp/测试-1ca8f20c3deccbf7aabe625397e2d3
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.iqunxing.cashier.Context.contextInitialized(Context.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the second tomcat (started by SSH client), I got the correct folder name.

**UPDATE-3**

After setting -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 (was ANSI_X3.4-1968 when folder not created correctly), `File.mkdir()` still creates wrong folder but `Files.createDirectory(path)` works OK (shows correct Chinese character).

**RESOLVED**

Hint by zapl, after adding `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in catalina.sh , File.getCanonicalPath no longer returns wrong folder name.

Comment: Are you certain your console is capable of displaying those symbols? It may well be your console doesn't have those *glyphs*.

Comment: I think my console has no problem, because I can see the correct symbols from log.

Comment: Try using [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead of File.

Comment: @vgr , how can I mkdir for a **Path** ?

Comment: can't reproduce your issue: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/02c51299e7d3ac68ce2bdfdb185c77a2 (java 1.8.0_91 on ubuntu14.04)

Comment: I got a correct folder on one machine and got a wrong folder on another. There must be some different settings between 2 OS or JVM , but I cannot find out them :-(

Comment: Testing whether different java versions make a difference should be fairly easy. Ps: `Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("/tmp", "测试-" Bytes.toH ...)));` is the mkdir for the new paths

Comment: Does the editor use the same encoding as the javac compiler? Edit the .java with an encoding aware programmer's editor like Notepad++ or JEdit.

Comment: same war files. And no problems in decompile .class file.

Comment: @zapl , see UPDATE-2

Comment: Odd. The error message leads to more results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413421/git-error-malformed-input-or-input-contains-unmappable-chacraters Maybe setting `LC_CTYPE` gets rid of the problem with `mkdir()`?

Comment: @zapl , after adding `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in catalina.sh , File.getCanonicalPath no longer returns wrong folder name :-)